# How to set variable type as class name in c#?

Tags: c#

I am new to c#. I have below code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car car;

            car = new Car("Red");
            Console.WriteLine(car.Describe());

            car = new Car("Green");
            Console.WriteLine(car.Describe());

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }

    class Car
    {
        private string color;

        public Car(string color)
        {
            this.color = color;
        }

        public string Describe()
        {
            return "This car is " + Color;
        }

        public string Color
        {
            get { return color; }
            set { color = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Here i am confused with variable "car". In the code declared as type car, so can we give class name as variable type?

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine - so what are you trying to do differently that you aren't doing now?

Comment: @BradPit if you are confused about `Classes, Instance vs Static etc` I would suggest a google search on C# Tutorials for beginners that would clear up a lot of things as you become more proficient

Comment: The thing is that i want to just understand what are the different data types that i can set to variable

Comment: @BraddPit you can declare a variable of any type you want.

Comment: @BraddPit you may want to look at doing a google search on `Explicit and Implicit` Declaration in that case as well..

Comment: @BraddPit I suspect you're looking for _reflection_, but it's not clear what you are wanting to _do_, and your questions are not clear.

Answer (score 3):

The name of your class is `Car` not `car`.`C#` is *case sensitive*. So the variable and the class have not the same name.

Comment: can i give car as a data type of variable car?

Comment: Yes i was just checking if it works or not. bcs i was confused to declare in this way.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `Car car;` you are declaring a new object called car and it's of type Car .